# How to mathematically express the smallest non-outlier element in a set?

Tags: statistics, notation

For example, in set $S$, what is the smallest element that is not an outlier? (An outlier being either $1.5(Q_3-Q_1)$ greater than $Q_3$ or less than $Q_1$)

Comment: When you write "the smallest number that is not an outlier" and provide a definition of "outlier" you have described that number mathematically. There is no "formula" for the number that will work on any data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is
$$
\min \{x \in S \mid x \geq 2.5Q_1 - 1.5Q_3\},
$$
but what you actually *need* is what you have already written down, as Ethan Bolker points out in the comments: a concise readable description of the element you are looking for.